# VS2012 compatibility with VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compatibility

So, I know that Microsoft enhanced their toolsets such that there is compatibility between applications and libraries built with VS2015, VS2017 and VS2019.

However, I thought that this combination would fail:
C++ application (.exe) built with the toolset from VS2012 (VC11), linking at runtime with
shared library (.dll) containing C++ built with the toolset from VS2019

However, we have seen that this combination "seems" to work.

I am expecting that combination to fail, but cannot explain its success.
Anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: maybe you confued it woth gcc compiled dlls

Answer (score 2):

The 'binary compatibility' covered on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160) between VS 2015 Update 3, VS 2017, and VS 2019 is specifically around the Standard C++ Library and static library linkage. Historically different generations of toolsets would fail to link or would crash at runtime. To avoid the crash, VS added these symbols so you'd get an error at link time instead:

```
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700' in CppFile1.obj
```

VS 2015 Update 3, VS 2017, and VS 2019 all use '1900' as the link stamp because they are designed and tested to work when mixed. Of course, it's important to note that the final link is expected to be against the newer CRT libs and linker (i.e. it's forward compatibility only). The link stamp is only pulled in when using C++ headers, not C headers or Win32 system headers.

> For example, if you had a C++ library that had inline functions that worked on a `std::vector` in the class implementation, and the rest of the class was hosted in a DLL, historically this would fail if you built with different toolsets because the implementation of `std::vector` would use different binary layouts, etc. This was the key value of having this 'binary compatibility' policy between toolsets so it would be easier to use the newest toolset and keep the majority of your existing 3rd party libraries and tools.

C ABIs via import libraries has always worked across compiler versions. That is in large part why Win32 APIs and COM APIs are hosted in DLLs and use C ABIs. Otherwise, every release of the compiler toolset would require a new set of OS libraries. In theory you could successfully link a program with VS 2019 using the libraries shipped in one of the ancient Platform SDKs.

So it really depends on exactly what your exe is using. If it's just using C APIs, extern "C" linkage, and/or Win32 APIs it would work pretty much no matter what combination you used.

**TL;DR:** Dynamic Link Libraries that use C ABIs work across toolsets. Static libraries or libraries with C++ ABIs only work across toolsets in specific scenarios.

> One more caveat here: Whole Program Optimization / Link-Time Code Generation static libraries are not compatible between toolsets.

Comment: I added a little info to my original question to be specific that the code in the application and the code in the DLL are all written in C++.

Comment: In the past, the same application built with, say, VS2008, would not be able to run when trying to load the DLL that was built with, say, VS2012; it would crash. And thus we are not sure why the VS2012/VS2019 combination is working

Comment: VS 2005 and VS2008 used Fusion side-by-side manifests to try to actively mange CRT servicing, which was fraught with problems and quirks.

Comment: So, are you saying I should accept it that it is working and just be happy about it?  :)

Comment: Pretty much. Oh, and don't count on it working like that every time :)